# Does Naruto consciously control his clones?

Tags: naruto

I've seen when Kakashi was training Naruto with his elemental affinity that Naruto cannot see what his clone is doing until it is undone. How does he control the clone? Does it move and think like a separate entity? Can it think to try to kill the original?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does it move and think like a separate entity?

Yes, the clones are completely independent, apart from the fact that Naruto can undo any clone he wishes to.

This can be seen when they collaborate and the fact that they need to communicate in order to do so. Note that when Naruto creates them, they know what he knows so he can *think* of a plan, create the clones, and everybody knows their role in the plan without a need to discuss it—they are still independent.

> Can it think to try to kill the original?

Possibly. But seeing as they have a short life and have just been cloned, Naruto would have had to be thinking about that kind of thing himself already in order for a clone to really do that. And of course, since Naruto can undo a clone at will, it would mean that as soon as he senses a threat from a clone he can undo it.

Comment: Seeing as Naruto has had schizophrenic tendencies on some parts of the series, based on what you answered, his dark self can manifest in one of his clones. Hmm....

Comment: btw there is a filler episode in the anime, where his clones turn aginst him

Comment: @Vogel612 wasn't that a dream?

Comment: @iKlsR yeah. forgot that... has been a while and since then i stuffed my brains with programming and a sh*tload of awesome anime ;)

Comment: It's also shown multiple times in the anime that when Naruto takes sufficient damage, his clones disappear. I assume this is because he loses concentration, or something similar, so it seems like if a clone tried to kill him, the clone would disappear before doing anything too vital.